# Mypy + flake8: Is there any way to surpress warning of `F821 undefined name`

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, flake8

In the following code, flake8 say `F821 undefined name 'B'`. 
But for mypy, type hint for `f` is neccesary.
How to ignore such warnings by flake8?

```
def f(b: B) -> None:
    pass


class B():
    pass
```

This example can be solved trivially: change the order of declarations. 
But sometimes I cannot change the orders in realistic cases . 
Such misleading warnings are noisy for me.

My env: Python 3.6 + flake8 3.6.0 + mypy 0.641 + flake8-mypy 17.8.0

Comment: change `B` to `'B'` works for me.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `# noqa:` to silence some errors. Example:

test.py

```
def f(b: B) -> None:  # noqa: F821
    pass


class B():
    pass
```

bash

```
$ flake8 test.py
(return no error)
```

See also: http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.1.1/user/ignoring-errors.html#in-line-ignoring-errors

Answer (score 13):

This isn't a misleading warning and **should not be ignored**, running your code will lead to a crash currently:

```
$ python3.8 t.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 1, in <module>
    def f(b: B) -> None:
NameError: name 'B' is not defined
```

You have two options to fix this, one is to explicitly use a forward declaration (by wrapping the typename in quotes):

```
def f(b: 'B') -> None:
    pass


class B():
    pass
```

runtime:

```
$ python3.8 t.py
$ flake8 t.py
```

Or to use `from __future__ import annotations` (new in python3.7):

```
from __future__ import annotations


def f(b: B) -> None:
    pass


class B():
    pass
```

**NOTE**: I'm using flake8 3.7.x which also improved handling of forward annotations and type comments